# Not able to connect mysql db by toad on linux server which it is easily connected by putty or linux terminal?

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-error-1064, toad, database-connection

I have mysql DB on cloud linux server. I am able to connect db when I access it through the putty mean ssh connection.
But when I try to access this DB remotely by toad , it couldn't connect to the DB.

I tried edition my.cnf file also. But it has no entry regarding "skip-networking" or something which is preventing me to connect.

I couldn't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to mysql server through remote computer, you have to give explicit permission particularly to your IP address or computer name

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to '<username used to log in to mysql>'@'<IP Addess>'
```